# Can't create a texture with a simple box

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to render a simple blue box to a texture, so that I can pass the texture to ImGui to render it as an image. For some reason though, I only ever get a simply white texture, and I can't figure out why. I've stripped my class down to as simple a case that I can, but I still only ever get a solid white texture, instead of a blue box that takes up most of the screen.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

GLFWwindow * window;
GLuint solid_texture;

GLuint loadShaders(const char * vertex_file_source, const char * fragment_file_source)
{
    // Create the shaders
    GLuint vertex_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint framgent_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    glShaderSource(vertex_shader_id, 1, &vertex_file_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader_id);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader_id, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cerr << VertexShaderErrorMessage[0] << std::endl;
    }

    glShaderSource(framgent_shader_id, 1, &fragment_file_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(framgent_shader_id);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(framgent_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(framgent_shader_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(framgent_shader_id, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cerr << FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0] << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, vertex_shader_id);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, framgent_shader_id);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cerr << ProgramErrorMessage[0] << std::endl;
    }

    glDetachShader(ProgramID, vertex_shader_id);
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, framgent_shader_id);

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader_id);
    glDeleteShader(framgent_shader_id);

    return ProgramID;
}

void generate_solid_texture()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &solid_texture);

    // Solid texture
    unsigned char solidTexturePixels[4];
    solidTexturePixels[0] = ~0;
    solidTexturePixels[1] = ~0;
    solidTexturePixels[2] = ~0;
    solidTexturePixels[3] = ~0;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, solid_texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, solidTexturePixels);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);  // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 14 - Render To Texture", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 "
                "version of the tutorials.\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // We would expect width and height to be 1024 and 768
    int windowWidth = 1024;
    int windowHeight = 768;
    // But on MacOS X with a retina screen it'll be 1024*2 and 768*2, so we get the actual framebuffer size:
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true;  // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    // Hide the mouse and enable unlimited mouvement
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Set the mouse at the center of the screen
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024 / 2, 768 / 2);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Setup OpenGL shaders
    std::string vertex_shader_source =
        R""(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 color;
uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

out vec2 frag_uv;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_uv = uv;
    frag_color = vec4(color, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1);
}
)"";

    std::string fragment_shader_source =
        R""(
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D Texture;
in vec2 frag_uv;
in vec4 frag_color;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    // color = frag_color * texture(Texture, frag_uv.st);
    // color = vec4((frag_color * texture(Texture, frag_uv)).xyz, 1);
    color = frag_color * texture(Texture, frag_uv.st);
}
)"";

    GLuint program_id = loadShaders(vertex_shader_source.c_str(), fragment_shader_source.c_str());
    generate_solid_texture();

    // Heatmap objects
    GLuint m_vao, m_vbo, m_uvbo, m_cbo;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_uvbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_cbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uvbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_cbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);

    // Create the FBO for later
    GLuint fbo, map_texture;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &map_texture);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    GLsizei heat_map_width = 600;
    GLsizei heat_map_height = 600;

    std::vector<float> map_vertices, map_vertex_uvs, map_vertex_colors;

    std::vector<float> solid_uv = {0.0f, 0.0f};
    std::vector<float> bl = {0, 0}, br = {1.0f, 0}, tl = {0, 1.0f}, tr = {1.0f, 1.0f};
    map_vertices = {bl[0], bl[1], 1.0f, tr[0], tr[1], 1.0f, tl[0], tl[1], 1.0f,
                    bl[0], bl[1], 1.0f, br[0], br[1], 1.0f, tr[0], tr[1], 1.0f};
    map_vertex_uvs = {solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1], solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1], solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1],
                      solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1], solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1], solid_uv[0], solid_uv[1]};
    map_vertex_colors = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    glUseProgram(program_id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, map_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, heat_map_width, heat_map_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, map_texture, 0);

    // glViewport(0, 0, heat_map_width, heat_map_height);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.00f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    // Vertex buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_vertices.size() * sizeof(map_vertices[0]), map_vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // UV buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uvbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_vertex_uvs.size() * sizeof(map_vertex_uvs[0]), map_vertex_uvs.data(),
                 GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Color buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_cbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_vertex_colors.size() * sizeof(map_vertex_colors[0]), map_vertex_colors.data(),
                 GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    static const GLfloat identity_matrix[16] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    GLuint move_matrix_location = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "mv_matrix");
    GLuint projection_matrix_location = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "proj_matrix");
    GLuint texture_location = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "Texture");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(move_matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, solid_texture);
    glUniform1i(texture_location, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, map_vertices.size() / 3);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Framebuffer to texture
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Always check that our framebuffer is ok
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        return false;

    // The fullscreen quad's FBO
    static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
    static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_uv_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_color_data[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    GLuint quad_vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(quad_vao);

    GLuint quad_vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_buffer_data), g_quad_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint quad_uvbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_uv_data), g_quad_vertex_uv_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint quad_colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_color_data), g_quad_vertex_color_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    do {
        // Render to our framebuffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(
            0, 0, windowWidth,
            windowHeight);  // Render on the whole framebuffer, complete from the lower left corner to the upper right

        // Clear the screen
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(program_id);

        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        // Render on the whole framebuffer, complete from the lower left corner to the upper right
        glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(program_id);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, map_texture);
        // Set our "renderedTexture" sampler to use Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(texture_location, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(quad_vao);

        // Draw the triangles !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);  // 2*3 indices starting at 0 -> 2 triangles

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }  // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

I am fairly certain the issue is not with the vertex or fragment shaders, because I use them in another renderer class and that one works fine. Please let me know if I can provide anything else that would be of use.

Major Edit: I've created a minimal reproducible example of my issue.

Edit2: I believe I have updated it for the better, but now showing a black screen instead of a white one. I ran the `generate_solid_texture` function, enabled the verex atttrib arrays for the `quad_vao`, and set the framebuffer to default in the main loop.

Comment: I suggest debugging with [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/).

Comment: While that seems interesting, it doesn't seem to support Mac OS X.

Comment: On the first glance, I don't see anything wrong with the code. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: I tried to do that as much as possible. What would that entail for this problem? Drawing to an image or something?

Comment: Something we can compile and run with minimal effort, that reproduces the problem (displays a white texture, instead of what you expected). I'd say a single file, with as few dependencies as possible (ImGui + whatever you open a window with).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat please take a look at the edit. I've managed to make such a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently `glClear` at line 337 causes `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`, not sure why yet.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat most likely because it is called on an incomplete FBO, since the color buffer is detached in line 276 and the draw buffer is still left of the default to color attachment 0.

Comment: `quad_vao` has never any vertex attribs enabled

Comment: `solid_texture` is used unitialized and never created

Comment: the viewport is not set appropriately when initially rendering to the `fbo`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have edited the source file as I noted, but now I'm getting a black screen instead of a white one. Still no blue box yet though.

Comment: That's because you draw a black quad.

Comment: How am I rendering a black quad? I have the clear color set to black for the texture, but the box in the texture should be blue, but is not showing up.

Comment: Your color for your quad is all black, and multiplying that with some texture colors still yields black.

Comment: I've updated it to use white on the quad, and it's still all black.

Comment: Interestingly, it does create some blue quads for me. Your viewport when rendering into the texture is still wrong, and your uv coords for the quad don't make much sense, but you should get some result.

Comment: Finally. It seems that the overall issue for me was that I didn't call glViewport before drawing to the texture (thanks for the tip). After I changed that, I got the blue quads, which yes, I saw how the uv's were messed up. I think that Macs need the glViewport call. Maybe the API for your system differed in that?